# Тонкости отправки JSON POSTом с помощью Retrofit 2

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

Доброго времени суток.

Объясните, кто знает, как так получается что при отправке одного и того же джейсона различаются результаты.

```
//кусок интерфейса Retrofit2
@Headers("Content-Type: "+Api.CONTENT_TYPE)
@POST(THAT_URL)
Call<String> singIn(@Body String BODY);

>>RESPONCE errbody: {"status":400}


//корректно работающая альтернатива на OkHttp3
 RequestBody reqBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Api.CONTENT_TYPE),BOBY);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(THAT_URL)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", Api.CONTENT_TYPE)
            .post(reqBody)
            .build();
    okhttp3.Response resp = client.newCall(request).execute();

>>RESPONCE errbody: {"status":200}
```

Собственно вопрос, почему есть разница? Что я упустил?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в том, что для отправки строки, коим является json, необходимо просто добавить в билдере ретрофита следующий код:

```
.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
```

Об этом на английском можно почитать [тут](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-send-plain-text-request-body).